# How to bind the ng-repeat variable to a custom angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

In Angular (v1.3) how do you bind the variable from an ng-repeat to a custom directive?

All the examples seem to bind to a $scope variable instead.  eg given a list of products and a custom directive called product, how can we do something to this effect:

```
<li ng-repeat="product in products">
    <product item="product" />
</li>
```

Where the directive is created as:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var productDirective = function () {
        return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {item: '='},
                templateUrl: '/views/product.html',                 
            };
    };

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .directive('product', productDirective);

})();
```

And it has a very simple template:

```
<p>{{item.name}} {{item.price}}</p>
```

This fails because scope: '=' only binds to $scope, not to ng-repeat.

I was able to get it to work with

```
return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {item: '@'},
            templateUrl: '/views/product.html',

            link: function(scope, element, attributes){
                scope.item = scope.$eval(attributes.item);
            }
        };
```

But the usage of $eval is not really acceptable of course (bad style).

What is the correct angular way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> This fails because scope: '=' only binds to $scope, not to ng-repeat.

I don't quite understand what you mean by the above, but the `=` in the bindings context is useful when you bind an *object* from the parent scope of the directive - *which is in fact the controller where you have used the `product` directive* - to the isolated scope of the directive, and NOT the `ng-repeat`.

Therefore, in  your case, you don't actually need to bind an object from a parent controller, to the directive's isolated scope with the `$eval` trick.

Just make sure that in the particular *parent* controller you have defined the array of `products` properly.

Here's a [***Demo***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/8b6sLjd1/) of how you can get it working.

Answer (score 1):

> This fails because scope: '=' only binds to $scope, not to ng-repeat.

It should **NOT** fail because `ng-repeat` creates a scope for every iteration and puts the current `product` to it along with the other loop vars like `$index`. So, the `product` is actually on the scope and you can bind to it normally.

I created a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6aorzmse/) with no changes to your code to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a controller to the productDirective:

```
 var productDirective = function () {
    return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {item: '='},
            templateUrl: '/views/product.html',
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {}]
        };
 };
```

Comment: What does that do?  It hasn't made a difference, the template is not binding and still displays blank.

Comment: I created a plnkr to demonstrate:  https://plnkr.co/edit/t2CVoeUCz8WEy1UhR9J5?p=preview